# Read From XML (List inside List) into Java Class Using Serializer

Tags: java, android, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I did serialize same as this example without list inside list

but Cannot Serialize xml to list if its inside another list.the code of all classes and xml bellow :

Read Code:

```
PaymentEBillList bills = null;
try {
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    bills = serializer.read(PaymentEBillList.class, output);
} catch (Exception e) {     

}
```

the list of Bills is null after executing code

PaymentEBillList Class:

```
@Root(name="ArrayOfPaymentBill")
public class PaymentEBillList {

    @ElementList(required=true, inline=true)
    public List<PaymentBill> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

PaymentBill Class:

```
@Root(name="PaymentBill")
public class PaymentBill {
    @Element
    public String SerialNumber;
    @Element
    public String CustomerName;
    @Element
    public String TotalAmount;
    @Element
    public EBillList EBill;
    public PaymentBill()
    {
        super();
    }
    public PaymentBill(String SerialNumber, String CustomerName, String 
    TotalAmount,EBillList EBill) {
        super();
        this.SerialNumber = SerialNumber;
        this.CustomerName = CustomerName;
        this.TotalAmount = TotalAmount;
        this.EBill= EBill;
    }
}
```

EBillList Class:

```
@Root(name="Bill")
public class EBillList {
    @ElementList(required=true, inline=true)
    public List<EBill> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

EBill Class:

```
@Root(name="EBill")
public class EBill
{
    @Element
    public String NB;
    @Element
    public String Amount;
    public EBill()
    {
        super();
    }
    public EBill( String NB,String Amount) {
        super();
        this.NB = NB;
        this.Amount = Amount;
    }
}
```

XML :

```
<ArrayOfPaymentBill>
    <PaymentBill>
        <SerialNumber>1</SerialNumber>
        <CustomerName>XXX</CustomerName>
        <TotalAmount>4500.00</TotalAmount>
        <Bill>
            <EBill>
                <NB>1</NB>
                <Amount>2500.00</Amount>
            </EBill>
            <EBill>
                <NB>2</NB>
                <Amount>2000.00</Amount>
            </EBill>
        </Bill>
    </PaymentBill>
    <PaymentBill>
        <SerialNumber>2</SerialNumber>
        <CustomerName>YYY</CustomerName>
        <TotalAmount>2900.00</TotalAmount>
        <Bill>
            <EBill>
                <NB>1</NB>
                <Amount>2900.00</Amount>
            </EBill>
        </Bill>
    </PaymentBill>
</ArrayOfPaymentBill>
```

Any Suggestion to solve this issue

Comment: Can you specify how you get `output` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `PaymentBill.java` you should name `EBillList` according to XML:

```
@Element
public EBillList Bill;
```

or specify XML name in the annotation:

```
@Element(name = "Bill")
public EBillList EBill;
```

Comment: its just not working with serializer and after
        bills = serializer.read(PaymentEBillList.class, output);      the bills has null value ..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its work as its in question the issue because of mistake in XML as [Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8094213/alexey) edit question with correction of XML